# Springboot & Thymeleaf : HTML - > PDF conversion

Tags: java, html, spring, itext, thymeleaf

I have an error converting HTML to PDF

> ERROR:  'The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".'
>   org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TrAX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 3; The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

The project is Springboot and Thymeleaf based.

Springboot serves a form to the user with a series of check boxes. The form looks like this:

[image]

When the formdata is submitted to the backend it is put back into a copy of the HTML form, for rendering to PDF. I am using the technique outlined [here](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-To-Create-PDF-through-HTML-Template-In-Spring-Boot).

The POST controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/assessment")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute("assessemnt") Assessment assessment, BindingResult result, Model model,
                             HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus status) throws IOException {

    // GET A LIST OF ATTRIBUTES IN CLASS AND PUT IN MAP
    Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(assessment, Map.class);
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

    Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if (pair.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
            if (pair.getValue().equals(true)) {
                data.put(pair.getKey().toString(), "checked");
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        pdfGenaratorUtil.createPdf("assessmenttemplate.html",data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the assessmenttemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Assessment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/assessment.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" method="post">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 24445 + Flatly theme</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#section1" href="#collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="section1" class="panel-collapse collapse">

            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="section1Checkbox1" value="option1" th:field="*{needsAssessment.section1Checkbox1}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="section1Checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
                </div>
```

When the line

```
pdfGenaratorUtil.createPdf("assessmenttemplate.html",data);
```

Is run the stacktrace is

> ERROR:  'The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching
>   end-tag "".' org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't
>   load the XML resource (using TrAX transformer).
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 3; The
>   element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
>   "".

The error is clear - but if I upload the assessmenttemple.html to w3 validator it rightly complains about the th tags, but has no issue with the link tag not being closed.

Comment: So what if w3 validator says something different. The PDF renderer requires **XML formatted HTML**, w3 validator doesn't. Ignore what w3 validator says, and fix the issue identified by PDF renderer, since *it* is the one that needs to process the HTML. --- As you said *"error is clear"*, so why haven't you just fixed it already?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by closing all the  tags with />. I also had to close the Meta tag and all input tags.